# Why is os.fchmod not working with a socket file descriptor?

Tags: python, sockets, permissions, unix-socket

I'm trying to use `os.fchmod()` as specified in [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_fchmod.htm). However, when I pass in a file descriptor and a mode, I get back a vague "Invalid Argument" error.

```
import socket
import stat
import os

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
os.fchmod(s.fileno(), stat.S_IRWXO)
```

How do I fix this? The goal is to create a Unix Domain Socket with changed permissions ([this git issue](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/426) implies its possible).

Comment: This is on a non-windows OS?

Comment: No error when I ran it on my linux machine.

Comment: I'm running this on Mac OS.

Comment: Hmmm... it likely wouldn't work on windows because Winsock sockets are not file descriptors. On MAC, I don't know.

Comment: Specifically, the error I get is: "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument". I'm also running this in a terminal using python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `fchmod` man page on MacOS, one of the causes of `EINVAL` is listed as:

> `[EINVAL]           fildes refers to a socket, not to a file.`

Apparently *linux* (but not MacOS) supports "pre-setting" the mode so that when you eventually `bind`, it will get the mode you pre-set with `fchmod`. That is not guaranteed to work across OSes and clearly does not on MacOS (I would guess it also doesn't work on other Unix-like OSes).

I think you will need use the `umask` strategy mentioned in that git issue. You can then call `os.chmod` with the socket's path name *after* the bind to ensure that the mode is set exactly as you want it (`umask` only allows you to specify bits to be *cleared* from the mode).

As mentioned in the issue, the problem with `umask` is that there is only a single mask value, which is shared by all threads. If you have only a single thread, or all threads can use the same mask value for all files created, that isn't a problem. Otherwise, you would either need to implement some kind of cooperative locking around `umask` usage, or use the `fork` hack mentioned in the issue to do the `umask`/`bind` in another process.